# Перегрузка операторов unsigned int

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Почему перегруженный оператор не может принимать unsigned int?

Пример:

```
exampleClass& operator++(exampleClass& ex,unsigned int intt)
    {

    }
```

ошибка:

```
error: postfix ‘exampleClass& operator++(exampleClass&, unsigned int)’ must have ‘int’ as its second argument
  friend exampleClass& operator++(exampleClass& ex,unsigned int intt);
```

Answer (score 3):

`++` - либо унарный, либо постфиксный оператор. В любом случае он может принимать только *один-единственный* аргумент. И это ваш `exampleClass`. Больше у него нет никаких аргументов.

Опциональный т. наз. "второй" параметр в объявлении функции `operator ++` - фиктивный. Это "костыль", предназначенный для отличения постфиксного `++` от префиксного `++` при объявлении. Этот фиктивный второй параметр должен иметь тип `int`. Так требуют правила языка С++. Какой тип имеет этот второй "параметр" для вас значения иметь не должно, ибо фактически *принимать* вы его скорее всего никогда не будете.

Обратите также внимание на то, что объявление `operator ++` с дополнительным фиктивным параметром (типа `int`) перегружает именно *постфиксный* оператор `++` для вашего класса. Традиционно, *постфиксный* оператор `++` должен возвращать "старое", исходное значение своего операнда (значение до инкремента). Для выполнения этого требования обычно приходится возвращать результат такого `++` *по значению*, а не по ссылке. Что вы собрались делать внутри своего `++` и как вы планируете возвращать результат по ссылке - не ясно. Закрадывается подозрение, что на самом деле вы пытаетесь реализовать функциональность оператора `+=`, но зачем-то вцепились в `++`.

Comment: Если изменить unsigned int intt   на   int intt, то компилятор не выдает ошибки..

Comment: @RoarRaizZer Потому что в стандарте написано, что там должен быть простой `int`. *"Какой тип имеет этот второй "параметр" значения не имеет"* Имеется в виду, что тип `int` был выбран создателями языка по сути от балды. (А *не* то, что вы можете выбрать любой тип.)

Comment: @RoarRaizZer Так о том и речь. Язык требует, чтобы фиктивный параметр был именно типа `int`. Без вариантов. Зачем вы пытаетесь поменять его тип?

Comment: Еще вопрос, почему оператор член класса должен принимать только 1 параметр. В случае если вывести этот оператор из класса, то компилятор не выведет ошибку. И сможет принимать 2 параметра.

Comment: @RoarRaizZer: У нестатического члена класса всегда есть один "невидимый" параметр - указатель на сам объект класса `this`. Поэтому на самом деле количество параметров всегда получается одно и то же.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое @Ant

Comment: @AnT еще 1 вопрос :) . https://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/298t  тут исходник. При запуске выходит ошибка "Segmentation error" думаю проблема в ссылке оператора.

Comment: @Roar RaizZer ,  там у вас проблема, поскольку вы возвращаете ссыльку на локальный (временный) обьект. Просто нужно возвращать не ссыльку. Во вторых вам не нужно в методе класса прибегнуть к селекторам класса типа get  или к указателью this, для того чтобы иметь доступ к закрытым данным. Методы класса всегда имеют доступ к закрытым членам, а аргумент константная ссылька, поскольку вы его не собираетесь модифицировать:  Classs operator+(const Classs& cl2) {
Classs temp(a + cl2.a);
return temp;
}